# Handle multiple events using vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to handle events for multiple elements selected by id.

in jQuery you can do something like:

```
$(function () {

    $('#id_1, #id_2, #id_3').on('focus', function (e) {

        $('#output').html('');

    });

});
```

How would go about implementing that in vanilla Javascript.

Tried this :

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

    document.querySelector('#id_1, #id_2, #id_3').addEventListener('focus', () => {

        document.querySelector('#output').value = ''

    })

})
```

The problem is the Second version doesn't fire the handler.

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: `querySelector()` returns a single element. You need `querySelectorAll()`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Even so, `addEventListener` is DOM method, not `NodeList`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you can't call addEventListener on a querySelectorAll

Comment: I didn't say you could...

Answer (score 2):

`querySelector()` returns one match. Use `querySelectorAll()` to get all matches in a collection, and iterate over them with a `for` loop:

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll('#id_1, #id_2, #id_3');
for (let item of items) {
    item.addEventListener('focus', function(e) { ... });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make an array of selectors, then iterate over them and add the listener.

```js
const selectors = ['#id_1', '#id_2', '#id_3'];
selectors.forEach((selector) => {
  document.querySelector(selector).addEventListener('focus', () => {
    console.log('focused ' + selector);
  });
});
```

```html
<input id="id_1"><input id="id_2"><input id="id_3">
```

Comment: it's working, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `document.querySelectorAll` and iterate the result

```
document.querySelectorAll('#id_1, #id_2, #id_3').forEach( s => 
    s.addEventListener( "focus", function(e){
      console.log( "focussed " + e.currentTarget );
    }) //end addEventListener
); //end forEach
```

Answer (score 1):

The Document method [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) returns the first *Element* within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selector.

Try with [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) which returns a static (not live) *NodeList* representing a list of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors.

Then attach the event to each element one by one by using `forEach()`:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('#id_1, #id_2, #id_3').forEach(input => {
    input.addEventListener('focus', (el) => {
        console.log(input.id + ' focused');
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<input id="id_1"><input id="id_2"><input id="id_3">
```